# How do you specify common package versions in a common.props file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

We've got a simple common.props file that is basically doing what Directory.Build.props appears to do. It specifies various settings and is then imported to the csproj files that need it.

Here's the basics of the MyProject.common.props file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    // some settings
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    
    //some more settings...

    <MyNewVariable>3.1.22</MyNewVariable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's the basics of the csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <Import Project="..\..\folderA\MyProject.common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="$(MyNewVariable)" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I use this approach I get the error:

> Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices does
> not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the
> dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.

However, if I just input 3.1.22 where the variable is it works fine. This suggests to me that the variable is coming through empty or not being picked up. If I remove the variable altogether and leave the Version blank I get the same error. I also double checked the path to the file by misspelling the import and I get a different error, so I know it can at least find the common.props file.